# Reducing libtensorflow.so file

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to integrate Tensorflow library with C++ interface into my C++ application. The problem is that straightforward build with

```
bazel build (some options) //tensorflow:libtensorflow.so
```

Makes a libtensorflow.so file that is 168Mb. That's way too much for my app. I've found some guides on reducing library size for Android, but can't find any for general desktop builds targets.

I assume that libtensorflow.so has all the whistles of TF, but what I really need is an inference engine with basic Conv ops, etc.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to experiment with the [CMake build](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/cmake). It has two interesting build options for your case:

- setting `tensorflow_BUILD_CONTRIB_KERNELS=OFF` does not build kernels from `tf.contrib`.
- setting `tensorflow_BUILD_ALL_KERNELS=OFF` builds only a small parts of the most common kernels.